# delete @ids and text contain link from messages of telegram bot

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a telegram bot and I want to delete all links from text , but here , I Have two problems :

1.I don't know how to delete all Ids like this : `@id`  with current regex that i have in my code

2.Also I want to delete all strings that have links (in telegram for add link to a text , select text and right click > formatting >create link, then  the color of your text will turn blue and your text will become a link)

so this is my current code and delete links from input :

```
bot.on("text", async function (msg){
  const text = msg.text.replace(
    /\b((?:[a-z][\w-]+:(?:\/{1,3}|[a-z0-9%])|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}\/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'".,<>?«»“”‘’]))/g,
    ""
  );

  console.log(text);
})

bot.start();
```

But I want delete ids (everything after @) and the text contain links

*also I use **TeleBot** for using telegram bot*

Answer (score 1):

You could add an alternation `|` matching an @ followed by any char except @ or a whitespace char to your pattern using `|\B@[^\s@]+`

**Note** that for a match only you can turn the outer capture group for the first part to a non capture group as you replace the match only with an empty string.

```
\b(?:(?:[a-z][\w-]+:(?:\/{1,3}|[a-z0-9%])|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}\/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'".,<>?«»“”‘’]))|\B@[^\s@]+
```

[See a regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QCfO6P/1)

Answer (score 0):

just use this

```
.*\B@(?=\w{5,32}\b)[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:_[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*.*
```

its remove all thing after @